# How to add multiple values to CtAnnotation in inria Spoon

Tags: java, annotations, inria-spoon

I am using Spoon 8.2.0 and have tried with Spoon 8.3.0 beta 10 as well: In the code below I try to add more than one value to an annotation, but it does not work as expected. I have a Java annotation `Summary` in *Summary.java*:

```
package tryspoon;

public @interface Summary {
    String title();
    String date();
}
```

In `Spooner` *Spooner.java*

```
package tryspoon;

import spoon.Launcher;
import spoon.SpoonAPI;
import spoon.reflect.declaration.CtAnnotation;
import spoon.reflect.reference.CtTypeReference;

public class Spooner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpoonAPI spoon = new Launcher();

        CtTypeReference<Summary> typeRef = spoon.getFactory().createCtTypeReference(Summary.class);
        CtAnnotation<Summary> annotation = spoon.getFactory().createAnnotation(typeRef);

        annotation.addValue("title", "First summary");
        annotation.addValue("date", "2020-10-05");

        // This outputs @tryspoon.Summary(date = "2020-10-05")
        System.out.println(annotation);

        // This outputs {date="2020-10-05", title=null}
        System.out.println(annotation.getAllValues());
    }
}
```

Swapping the order of `annotation.addValue("title", "First Summary")` and `annotation.addValue("date", "2020-10-05")` will make it only the `title` key and value be displayed
in the annotation, and the `date` key being null in the map from `getAllValues()`.

Comment: Maybe a bug, would you report it on Github? Thanks!

Comment: I reported as https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/3639